# Efficient way to create unknown number of object instances

Tags: java, class, instance, instantiation

I need to create a number of instances of a class and add them to an array (I am currently using an ArrayList, but I can change that if necessary). I need to do that for about 20 other classes, each with different a different amount of instances. What would be a more efficient way of doing this rather than writing a for loop for each item?

e.g.

```
  ArrayList<Tile> bag = new ArrayList<Tile>();
  num_tile_a = 10;
  num_tile_b = 6;
  num_tile_c = 4;
  num_tile_d = 8;

  for (int i = 0; i < num_foo; i++){
      bag.add(new Tile_a());
  ....
```

EDIT: In this example, Tile_a, Tile_b, Tile_c, and Tile_d are all different child classes of the Tile class.

Comment: You want 10 instances of foo, 6 instances of bar, etc?

Comment: If you need separate instances, you can only loop (or loop through streams in Java 8), as `Arrays.fill` will only create one instance.

Comment: So there isn't a way around this?

Comment: @NickJarvis What is the problem, though? Why do you not like doing it this way?

Comment: @Gendarme I have about 24 different classes, each with a specific number of instances needed. I was wondering if there was a way around writing 24 for loops.

Comment: @NickJarvis you could write one loop that loops to the largest number and  have if statements for all the differerent classes' numbers but thats probably just as much code

Comment: You can't fully "factorize" this and use reflection, as you can't create generic arrays. However you should be able to have a factory class with various utility methods that return a populated array based on the number of elements you desire.

Comment: @Mena So create another class to handle this? I guess that would help scalability, right?

Comment: @NickJarvis I can't tell you how would that impact on scalability per se, but using the factory pattern to create your objects (in this case, your arrays) with a desirable number of instances as parametrized might be a good idea, as long as the number of different types is limited/manageable. If this is something that's going to change a lot, then you'd actually be complicating your life even more. But in that last case, you probably have a design issue already...

Comment: @Mena This is for tiles in a game. There are 24 unique tiles, but I will probably add more later, and there are a unique number of each tile. I can't really think of a better way to handle this though. I'll try the factory that you and imps have mentioned.

Comment: @NickJarvis yes imps' answer likely goes the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment so I'll post a reply...the way to go against writing 24 different loops would be to have a map from a factory that can create the object to the number of objects.

Something like

```
interface <T> IFactory {
 T create();
}
```

And then just have a factory for each class you have.

```
Map<IFactory,Integer> factoryToNumOfInstances;
```

Another option would be if each of these classes has a default Constructor and you don't use any generics you can have a map of

```
Map<Class,Integer> classToNumOfInstances;
```

and just call the method newInstance();

```
clazz.newInstance();
```

Comment: Each class has just a default constructor with no arguments, so this looks like it will work. What does the Map do?

Comment: Hmm, where do you get rid of the loop? You still need to call `factory.create()`  or `clazz.newinstance()` as many times as you need to have instances. Using both patterns will ease expanding the creation logic to new (sub-)classes and avoid unrolling the creation for every potential (sub-)class involved.  Likely you had this in mind, but an innocent reader might miss that.

Comment: @NickJarvis The map would be just to tell you how many instances you need to create. How many times you call the factory method.

Comment: @rpy You get rid of having to write a loop for each class :)
You just iterate over the map with all the values and for each key of the map create a new instance, value times.